# R curve drawing not expected line

Tags: r

I have this R code:

```
mm_fn <- function(x){
  (x)/(1+2*x)
}

curve(mm_fn, -10,10)
```

And this draws the function but with a vertical line that I think it is not expected to be.

Would you have any idea why?

Best

Comment: What value woud your function have in -1/2? And approaching -1/2 from left and right?

Comment: yes, the fucntion is not defined for -1/2, but I don't know why R draws this line

Comment: Because default type for `curve()` is `lines()`. `lines()` connects all point one after another with line segment.  So connecting -1/2 - ϵ and  -1/2 + ϵ gives you almost vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrey Kolyadin has said, curve by default draws lines, so there is two options, or draw points instead, or add lines in two commands:

```
mm_fn <- function(x){
  (x)/(1+2*x)
}
curve(mm_fn, -10,-0.51, xlim=c(-10,10), ylim = c(-25, 25) )
curve(mm_fn, -0.49,10, add = T )
```

Comment: `curve(mm_fn, -10, 10, n = 10e4, type = "p", ylim = c(-10, 10), pch = ".")`

Comment: Why not `curve(mm_fn, -10, 10, n = 2e2 + 1)`? Or any `n` than will land in `0.5` (`n=length(seq.int(-10, 10, by = .5**n))`)?